# How to save blob files in database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, blob, h2

I have this Entity class

```
@Entity
public class ScannedFile {

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Blob content;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private byte[] photo;
}
```

And I tried to save the image file in database. I found two solutions and I have tried both. But none of them is working for me. Here is what I tried

**1. using byte array**

```
private Part file1; 

public String upload() throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = file1.getInputStream();
    ScannedFile created = new ScannedFile();
    created.setId(this.scannedFile.getId());
    byte[] photo = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    created.setPhoto(photo);
    ScannedFile newScannedFile = this.scannedFileRepository.save(created);        
}
```

**Problem:** Uploaded photo is not being saved in database. But it does not give any error either. What am I missing here.

**2. Using blob**

```
private static void initSession() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}

private static void endSession() {
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
}

private Part file1;

public String upload() throws IOException{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    InputStream inputStream = file1.getInputStream();
    Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(inputStream, 200);
    ScannedFile created = new ScannedFile();
    created.setContent(blob);
    ScannedFile newScannedFile = this.scannedFileRepository.save(created);
    endSession();
}
```

**Problem:** I get this error `hibernate.cfg.xml not found`. But I don't really want to use this xml file. So how can I get rid of this error and save the uploaded image in database.

Note: I am learning spring and jsf for couple of days now. I am using both jsf and spring in the same application. I am also using h2 database.

Comment: Could you please describe the `Table` that you are using here?

Comment: ScannedFile is the table. I checked it from h2 console

Comment: you can also watch this video explanation of adding BLOBs in database https://youtu.be/JQz_8dkLyJ8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got your problem. Use `@Lob` in your `@Entity` for `private byte[] photo;`